# Using ASM to monitor java.lang.ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, bytecode, instrumentation, java-bytecode-asm

I was hoping to create a monitor using ASM instrumentation to log calls to java.lang.ProcessBuilder. However, my attempts seem to fail. Some sample code is below. Basically, this code just adds a nop to the constructor of java.lang.ProcessBuilder and then writes the new (and original) class file to a modified-class directory. This is entirely for testing as I wanted to make sure things were working correctly and I could inspect the changed bytecode outside of running the agent. If I point this sample code at a different (non-java.lang) class everything works. Is it possible to modify the java.lang.ProcessBuilder using a javaagent?

Thanks in advance,

Jeremy

```
public class Instrumentor {

public static void agentmain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation instrumentation) {
    instrument(instrumentation);
}

public static void premain(String agentArgument, Instrumentation instrumentation) {
    instrument(instrumentation);
}

private static void instrument(Instrumentation instrumentation) {
    try {
        instrumentation.addTransformer(new SampleTransformer());
    } catch (TransformerException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Instrumentor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
}

//--------------------------------
public class SampleTransformer implements ClassFileTransformer {

public SampleTransformer() throws TransformerException {
}

@Override
public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className, Class<?> classBeingRedefined,
        ProtectionDomain protectionDomain, byte[] classfileBuffer) throws IllegalClassFormatException {
    if ("java/lang/ProcessBuilder".equals(className)) {
        System.out.println("attempting to process " + className);
        ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(classfileBuffer);
        ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(cr, ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS);
        SampleClassAdapter adapter = new SampleClassAdapter(cw);
        cr.accept(adapter, 0);
        byte[] clz = cw.toByteArray();
        try {
            System.out.println("write " + className);
            File p = new File("target\\modified-classes\\");
            p.mkdirs();
            File f = new File(p, className.replace('/', '.') + ".class");
            File o = new File(p, className.replace('/', '.') + ".original.class");
            Files.write(Paths.get(f.getAbsolutePath()), clz);
            Files.write(Paths.get(o.getAbsolutePath()), classfileBuffer);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SampleTransformer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return clz;
    }
    return classfileBuffer;
}
}
//------------------------
public class SampleClassAdapter extends ClassVisitor {

public SampleClassAdapter(ClassVisitor cv) {
    super(Opcodes.ASM5, cv);
}

@Override
public void visit(int version, int access, String name, String signature, String superName, String[] interfaces) {
    super.visit(version, access, name, signature, superName, interfaces);
}

@Override
public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String desc, String signature, String[] exceptions) {
    MethodVisitor mv = super.visitMethod(access, name, desc, signature, exceptions);
    if (mv != null && "<init>".equals(name)) {
        mv = new SampleMethodAdapter(mv, access, name, desc);
    }
    return mv;
}
}
//----------------------------------------
public class SampleMethodAdapter extends AdviceAdapter {

public SampleMethodAdapter(final MethodVisitor methodVisitor,
        final int access, final String name, final String descriptor) {
    super(Opcodes.ASM5, methodVisitor, access, name, descriptor);
}

@Override
protected void onMethodEnter() {
    mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.NOP);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the class at runtime but to start with I suggest trying to compile you own version which you override on the boot class path.  Once you have this working you can work what ASM is required to make this code injection work at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was. The ClassReader call to accept needed to include the EXPAND_FRAMES flag.

```
cr.accept(adapter, ClassReader.EXPAND_FRAMES);
```

After correcting this call I was able to successfully modify the byte code of java.lang.ProcessBuilder.